# CompositeId + HasMany doubles the field in the DB

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have such mapping for ProductVariant table:

```
Id(x => x.Id).Nullable();
Map(x => x.IsEnabled);
Map(x => x.ProductVariantName).Length(45);
Map(x => x.Description);
HasMany(x => x.TestCaseOrdered);
Map(x => x.CreatedDate);
```

And TestCaseOrder class like this one:

```
 CompositeId().KeyReference(x => x.TestCaseData).KeyReference(x => x.ProductVariant);
 Map(x => x.TestCaseOrder);
 Map(x => x.TestCaseSetName).Length(45);
```

But NHibernate generates table TestCaseOrder with two ProductVariant columns:

1) ProductVariant with Primary Key and Not Null.

2) ProductVariantId like a foreign key to the ProductVariant table.
They always have the same data

But I need only one field. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like a conventionmismatch. Specifying `HasMany(x => x.TestCaseOrdered).KeyColumn("ProductVariantId");` and 
`.KeyReference(x => x.ProductVariant, "ProductVariantId");` should solve it